# How to (manually) derive site URL from complete URL?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I've created an application where the user has to enter a site URL (plus credentials etc). I want to explain how to get from an URL in the browser's address bar to the site URL, e.g. from:

```
https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

to:

```
https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/
```

Experienced users will derive the rule by common sense but for the uninitiated this may be a challenge. Is there a general rules that one can use as guidance?

Comment: not sure what/why you would want something like this, but why dont you simply remove everything yourself that appears after /sitepages or /pages or /list1/forms/...

Comment: You could write some custom javascript code using the _spPageContextInfo object to pull the web absolute url out of the url, which should be what you're looking for if I understand your issue correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If You are using Client Side, then you can use

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl` or `_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl`

to fetch the web absolute url.